# ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer on MAC

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

I don't understand why but I can't connect to my school server from my network at home. I'm using login as always like ssh name@host.com but it still don't work.
Here is debug report with -v

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to merlin.fit.vutbr.cz [147.229.176.19] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/martinpristas/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/martinpristas/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/martinpristas/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/martinpristas/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Is here any options like network settings or mac settings to fix it ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Something is killing the TCP connection after it's established while SSH is trying to log in.  I get the same error for that particular host from here, so it's probably a firewall closer to the server than closer to you.

If you don't have control over that firewall, there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error connecting to the server. What I did was to change my internet service provider and everything was fine.